# Change name of SSL certificate in AWS Loadbalancer listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS.I have imported and added the SSL certificate to my listener in AWS load balancer successfully.However now I'm in need to change the certificate name alone.I could not find any direct options to change the certificate name. Any ways to modify it?

Comment: What name are you referring to? The common name? That cannot be changed in-place, but you can issue a new SSL certificate.

Comment: Are you refereing to tag(with which you want to know the certificate)?

Comment: @luk2302 I'm referring to Name or domain of the SSL certificate. Incase if it cant be changed then can i remove the SSL certificate and add it again with correct name.

Comment: @Riz No it is not tag thing

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the domain of an SSL certificate already commissioned. But you can remove the existing SSL certificate and add a new SSL certificate.

This may help you.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-update-ssl-cert.html